# Json serialization of array iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ipad

I am trying to create a string from the object using json serialization

Input i have

```
NSDictionary *sampledict = @{@"TextVal": @"10233"};
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sampledict];
```

Output required

```
[{\"testval\":\"10233\"}]
```

What i tried

```
    NSDictionary *sampledict = @{@"TextVal": @"10233"};
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sampledict];
    NSData *innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:0 error:NULL];
    NSString *innerJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:innerJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog(@"%@",innerJsonString);

   // NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   // [dict setObject:innerJsonString forKey:@"sampleId"];

    NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:innerJsonString options:0 error:NULL];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

and it crashed as

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization
>   dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON
>   write'

**The crash is because it doesnt have a top level dict,Put in an dictionary it is solved.But how to get this json from this object?**

Comment: Input and output is specified in the question .Please see the qn

Comment: Oops sorry ..Typo.. will correct it..Pls see qn nw

Comment: First off, are you ***SURE*** you really want the JSON in that format??  It's "inner JSON" format that is occasionally used, but it's also possible to get confused (due to various debug printing oddities) into believing that the `\\` characters should be there when they shouldn't.

Comment: The output is (still) NOT JSON. Why do you think a JSON parser/serializer can help?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is trying to generate JSON string from an object that is in turn is a string:

```
[dict setObject:innerJsonString forKey:@"sampleId"];
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:innerJsonString options:0 error:NULL]; //innerJsonString is a string that can't be serialized as JSON
```

Change it to:

```
[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"sampleId"];
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
```

and it should work.

**Edit**
For your specific output requirement, you can use:

```
NSDictionary *sampledict = @{@"TextVal": @"10233"};
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sampledict];
NSData *innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *innerJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:innerJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",innerJsonString);
```

But I think you are already getting the required JSON from the first part of your code and you have solved it by yourself :)

Comment: Pls see the "output required".I know wht the error means and how it can be resolved .My question is how to create tht output

Comment: Well, to be specific `[\"testval\":\"10233\"]` is not a valid JSON. [] in JSON, represents an array that is essentially indexed by some number and not by some key, like, "festival". So if you are really trying to get a valid JSON, the structure would look something like `{\"testval\":\"10233\"}`, that represents a JSON object. And the first part of your code returns something similar in `innerJsonString.`

Comment: However, if you are really desperate to get the invalid JSON as output, please follow my edit.

Comment: It was a typo in qn..Pls chk it nw

Answer (score 2):

As the error message tells you, the top level type (NSString) is not a valid top level JSON type. Only dictionaries and arrays are valid top level objects in JSON. Your app is crashing on the line you're trying to convert a string to a top level JSON object:

```
NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:innerJsonString options:0 error:NULL];
```

Replacing `innerJsonString` with `dict` should fix the problem.

Comment: Pls see the "output required".I know wht the error means and how it can be resolved .My question is how to create tht output

Comment: I just realized that your output is not valid JSON. There are no associative arrays (as in php for example). Either you'll get `{"testval":"10233"}` or `["testval", "10233"]`.

Comment: It was atypo in qn pls chk it nw